# Facebook KeyHash Issue: Mismatching with store key hash

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, hash

I know, this question is asked many times. But I am again suffering with this issue. I have first created a key hash using the command line:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\admin\.android\debug.keystore" | "D:\Work\FL\SocialNetwork\openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "D:\Work\FL\SocialNetwork\openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32\bin\openssl.exe" base64
```

Which has given me a key: 7sfF8f3iv6txnCqYW4zoK3lQRBM=

Now I have added this key hash on the Facebook App Settings. And then compiled and run my android app. But unfortunately I am getting the below exception in my logcat:

```
Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.com.facebook.FacebookAuthorizationException: UnknownError: ApiException:Key hash Dfd2yTJmYckjhuASsVgSXLJ_Tso does not match any stored key hashes.
```

So it is quite mismatch of the hash key. But what will be the correct key. I have generated the hash key using my code as it has been suggested in different posts:

```
try {
          PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                  "com.social.socialnetworking", 
                  PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
          for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
              MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
              md.update(signature.toByteArray());
              Log.d("Testing:", "Hi key ::  "+Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
              }
      } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

      } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

      }
```

This has returned me the following key: torTZ0ApYu3ylNnPUj7fcAjMsfQ=

Now when i have tried with this key and ran the app again, it gave me the same error.

Now i am amazed what i should do with this integration of facebook. Is it the issue with my key tool? Can anyone please give me the correct solution. I have literally tried different option and tired also.

Please help..

Comment: did you try adding the key given to you in the error message?

Comment: Yes..Now i am able to resolve it. The issue was in the above code package name was slightly wrong. So it was a giving wrong hash key. And I have tried adding the key given in the error message. But that did not work. One more point i want to say here: in the facebook settings hash key box, don't remove any hash keys. Just add them if you are generating multiple hask key. I was doing this wrong also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes..Now i am able to resolve it. The issue was in the above code package name was slightly wrong. So it was a giving wrong hash key. And I have tried adding the key given in the error message. But that did not work. One more point i want to say here: in the facebook settings hash key box, don't remove any hash keys. Just add them if you are generating multiple hask key. I was doing this wrong also. –